# Personalizar barra de volume player html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html5-audio

Amigos, tenho um player html5 com os controllers tudo padrão. Gostaria de fazer um controlador de volume nesse mesmo estilo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código até agora

```html
<audio id="demo" src="http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Reproduzir o áudio</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pausar o áudio</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Aumentar o volume</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Diminuir o volume</button>
</div>
```

e gostaria que no lugar desses botões que aparecem para aumentar e diminuir o volume fosse uma barra no mesmo estilo da que postei acima. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.
Grato desde já.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o "novo" `input type=range` com `min=0`, `max=1` e `step=0.1`, quando acontecer o `onchange` ele faz o assign do `volume` para `this.value`:

```html
    <audio id="demo" src="http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Reproduzir o áudio</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pausar o áudio</button>
</div>
<input type="range" id="weight" min="0" value="0.5" max="1" step="0.1" onchange="document.getElementById('demo').volume=this.value">
```

Comment: Obrigado! Era exatamente isso que procurava.